# Encrypt the plain text using public key in client App (html & js) and decrypt the encrypted data using private key in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, private-key

I have a requirement like

- Generate public/private keys in API and store in Data base
- Send the public key to client. Here client is plain html with jquery
- Client will encrypt the plain text using public key and send to api for further action
- API will decrypt the encrypted data using private key which is present in database

Here I am able to generate keys and able to encrypt data in client. But Unable to decrypt the encrypted data in API.

Code to generate Keys

```
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
                csp.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
                //Private key
                var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

                //Public key
                var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

                string privKeyString = string.Empty;

                var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                xs.Serialize(sw, privKey);
                privKeyString = sw.ToString();

                //Will be saved in sesssion for later use during decryption
                string privateKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privKeyString));
                //string privateKeyBase64 = ConvertPrivateKeytoString(privKey);

                //This will give public key in the following format which is required by the JS library
                //-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                //-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
                publicKey = ConvertPublicKeyForJS(pubKey);
```

Code in JS

```
 var keySize = parseInt(2048);
            var encrypt = new JSEncrypt({ default_key_size: keySize });  
            encrypt.setPublicKey(pkey);
            var encryptedJson = encrypt.encrypt(emailParams);

            var emailParamsEncrypted = new Object();
            emailParamsEncrypted.PId = pId;
            emailParamsEncrypted.EncryptedData = encryptedJson;
```

Code for Decryption in API (C#)

```
string plainTextData = string.Empty;
                //read the private key from DB
                string privKeyString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(emailKeys.PrivateKey));

                var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(privKeyString);
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                var privKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);

                var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
                csp.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
                csp.FromXmlString(privKeyString);
                csp.ImportParameters(csp.ExportParameters(true));

                var bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
                //Array.Reverse(bytesCypherText);
                //var bytesCypherText1 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cypherText);

                //Problematic line
                var bytesPlainTextData = csp.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                plainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
```

Keys

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----  MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAztHqr8CkaC+XvlO/E0I4Zur/eYyJ8WyGZhgzVaZfo2STbf98IP6eQ+jiqIgGywk+EolTf6BubrCI+Hb/I1YSdEd0eI3VMgEpLWATdqvyFIOqdyf3G/ZOPpWvKrM5xMTb62zpzYMdcpizYPJaKn3v3nmt4lMiKM2fV8Yhym90qkvqckEtyiP3Z9xuusiXhbdBgFSXZI4wiV22pZvIoNcqV4xsCLvabnfP0ZZD/4e8CHeBfAzWFoiw3ZgrdgIHvoGFfsR/dI3pDN8kzExeXj3TLE7yHElykB6ROicHlCNsR3G5k2605W/YTbPs6MRRhbz2PdshyR82ewC7dhZu5+6kxQIDAQAB  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

```
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
```

Here, after decrypting I am getting empty byte[0]
[image]

why it is returning byte[0] ? What is the root cause for this prolem?
Can you please help me to get it solved

Comment: Why are you using Convert.FromBase64String? Does your client sends base64 encoded string?

Comment: If I use your keys, your JavaScript code for encryption and your C# code for decryption I _cannot_ reproduce the problem, i.e. `bytesPlainTextData` is _not_ empty. Perhaps your plaintext is too long, it may be max. 245 bytes here. Please post a sample plaintext (`emailParams`) and ciphertext, created with the posted keys. BTW, a later problem is that UTF8 must (presumably) be used instead of Unicode when decoding.

Comment: @Topaco, yes I am trying to encrypt large text. What would be the supported length to encrypt? How to encrypt large plain text?

Comment: _What would be the supported length to encrypt?_ See my last comment or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33445). For longer plaintexts, usually a symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) is applied or, if the symmetric keys are to be exchanged as well, a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is used, where an asymmetric encryption like RSA is applied for the exchange.